# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a AJAX POST call to an API using Javascript. Its giving me this error

```
    OPTIONS https://ethor-prod.apigee.net/v1/stores/HI6PIDO5JS/orders/calculate?apikey=wSgbv9PE8aJhDOI17vvTUX1NlAceUXG7 
Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. store.js:581
    calculateorder store.js:581
    onclick index-3.html:183
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ethor-prod.apigee.net/v1/stores/HI6PIDO5JS/orders/calculate?apikey=wSgbv9PE8aJhDOI17vvTUX1NlAceUXG7. 
Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. index-3.html:1
```

Below is the code thats causing this error

```
var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert("success");
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, HEAD");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age","1728000");   
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(calculate));
```

the url and variable calculate are totally fine. The conversion into JSON is perfect too. I tried the converted JSON with an HTTP client (RESTED). It worked perfectly, so the error is in the POST call, most probably related to headers and Cross origin resource sharing (CORS).

When I use the HTTP Client, this is the response header I am getting along with successful execution

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DC0DBDB6B877BD1CD67BBE4E20432BFD; Path=/v1.0/; HttpOnly
Server: nginx/1.4.5
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, HEAD
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Expires: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 21:20:44 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 21:20:44 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Any idea whats happening here? Why isn't it working through the browser? I tried it on Safari and Chrome both.

Comment: Don't you see the error you posted? `Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers` - the only header you're allowed to set apparently is `x-requested-with`, from the successful response

Comment: But I am setting the header "Content-Type" to "application/json" while using my HTTP client (as I am sending a JSON file with my POST request). I can show a screenshot if you want. It doesn't make sense that way, unless using an HTTP client is different than using a browser.

Comment: get rid of that custom mime content-type and the client-side headers and it should work just fine.

Comment: Can't do that, as thats how to API knows if I am sending an XML or a JSON to it. Tried removing it, gave the error 400 Bad Request.